# Calculating Cohen's kappa values

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to better understand Cohen's kappa coefficient to analyze some data.  I understand the equation and how to use it (I think), but I have a simple question.

If you navigate to the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) on Cohen's kappa, you'll find an example where 50 people are applying for a grant and two people (call them admissions people) are saying either "yes, fund it" or "no, don't fund it".  Consider the same example but with different values now.  Suppose person A says "yes" to all grants, and person B also says "yes" to all grants.  In this scenario, and following from the wiki article, the kappa value ends up being $0/0$, when in reality, it should be pretty high (and close to $1$) as both person A and B agreed on everything.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: How did you get $0/0$?  It looks to me like $\dfrac{1-\Pr(e)}{1-\Pr(e)}$.  That's not $0/0$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: What value would you assign to `Pr(e)`?